# What word am I describing?

Tags: word, language

Here's a puzzle answerable using only one word in the English language with five letters based on the following text.

स्तैन् ब्लीवस् सैवी

**Hint 1:**
Yaan ka'ap'éel capas ti' le talamilo'.

**Hint 2:**
ᐊᐃᑉᐸᖓ ᖃᓕᕇᑦ ᐅᓪᓗᓕᖅᓯᒪᔪᑦ ᐱᑐᖃᕐᓄᑦ ᓱᕖᑕᓐᒧᑦ, ᑎᐊᓐᒫᒃᒧᑦ, ᐊᒻᒪᓗ ᔮᒪᓂᒧᑦ.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> <s>Pearl.</s> **Beryl.**

The original clue, "स्तैन् ब्लीवस् सैवी" is

> A Devanāgarī transliteration. Transliterating into Latin script, we get "stain blīwas saiwī".

This is hinted at by the first hint, "Yaan ka'ap'éel capas ti' le talamilo'." which is

> Yucatec Maya. Bing translate renders it as "There are two layers to the problem."

The second hint, "ᐊᐃᑉᐸᖓ ᖃᓕᕇᑦ ᐅᓪᓗᓕᖅᓯᒪᔪᑦ ᐱᑐᖃᕐᓄᑦ ᓱᕖᑕᓐᒧᑦ, ᑎᐊᓐᒫᒃᒧᑦ, ᐊᒻᒪᓗ ᔮᒪᓂᒧᑦ." is Canadian Aboriginal syllabics, specifically, it is

> Inuktitut. In Latin script it reads "Aippanga qaliriit ulluliqsimajut pituqarnut Suviitanmut, Tianmaakmut, ammalu Jaamanimut." The last part of this reads "Sweden-ʟᴏᴄ, Denmark-ʟᴏᴄ, and Germany-ʟᴏᴄ". Bing translate renders the full sentence as "The second layers dated to the old Sweden, Denmark, and Germany."

This is a hint that

> The phrase "stain blīwas saiwī" is reconstructed Proto-West Germanic, a language hypothesized by some linguists to have been spoken in this range sometime between the 2ⁿᵈ and 7ᵗʰ centuries C.E.
>  "*stain blīwas saiwī" can be glossed as "stone <s>blue.ɢᴇɴ</s> **colour.ɢᴇɴ** sea.ɢᴇɴ", which can be roughly translated to English as "Stone of the <s>blue</s> **colour of the** sea." (Proto-West Germanic is not thought to have had definite articles at first.)

**Using this clue, we can note that**

> **The stone being referred to is probably aquamarine, a blue-green variety of beryl whose name comes from the Latin roots** ***aqua*** **(water) and** ***marīna*** **(of the sea (f.)). It is so-called due to its seawater colour. Further, beryl refers to a blue-green colour similar to that of the sea, and is thought to derive from the Greek** ***βήρυλλος,*** **which wikipedia claims referred to a "precious blue-green color-of-sea-water stone". (The citation provided does not evidence this claim, only that it "referred to a number of blue-green stones in antiquity". Further, the only other references I can find which make this claim are the books** ***Gem Hunter*** **(2015) and** ***A Writer's Guide to Crystals and Gemstones*** **(2023), which both postdate the addition of this claim to the Wikipedia article, unsourced, by editor Vsmith on 2004-12-19. I suspect that these are indeed credulous repetitions of Wikipedia's claim, for which I cannot find the original source.)**

Thus, the English five-letter word

> Corresponding to "stone of the <s>blue</s> **colour of the** sea" is <s>pearl</s> **beryl**.

<s>**ETA:**</s>

> I think 'coral' could also fit the clue.

Comment: Lbhe svany fgntrf ner jebat. "Fgnva oyījnf fnvjī" qbrf abg genafyngr gb "fgbar bs gur oyhr frn." Vg genafyngrf gb fbzrguvat engure qvssrerag.

Comment: @Galactic Zl onq, V gnxr vg *oyījnf vf gur travgvir bs *oyīh "pbybhe (a.)" naq abg *oyāh "oyhr (n.)" gura? Guvf jbhyq tvir n genafyngvba bs "Fgbar bs gur pbybhe bs gur frn". V nz pbasvqrag bs zl tybffvat bs gur bgure jbeqf. Va guvf pnfr gur bayl svir-yrggre jbeq V pbhyq guvax bs jbhyq or "orely".

Comment: Gung jnfa'g gur jbeq gung V jnf ybbxvat sbe, ohg V'yy tvir vg gb lbh. Sbe n obahf cbvag, svaq gur jbeq gung V'z ybbxvat sbe naq hcqngr lbhe nafjre. V'yy erjneq lbh jvgu gur terra purpxznex.

Comment: @Galactic V'yy nibvq ohzcvat gur dhrfgvba ol rqvgvat va pnfr V'z zvfgnxra, ohg jnf gur jbeq lbh jrer guvaxvat bs "yncvf", fubeg sbe "yncvf ynmhyv"? Vs vg'f abg, V guvax V pna snveyl or fnvq gb unir fgehpx bhg, naq V'yy yrnir vg gb fbzrbar ryfr gb znxr na nggrzcg.

Comment: Lrf, gung'f gur jbeq.